# Daily rep exceeded is wrong on /reputation while Stinking Badges has it right?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm sure this is already answered somewhere, but the questions I find about this topic all seem to date from the Great Rep Recalc of 2010.  On my /reputation page, it says:

```
days represented 1159
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 137 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits
```

But I have not been given a Legendary badge.  Recalcing the reputation doesn't change anything.

Using the [Stinking Badges](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/badge/) app, it says I've reached the rep cap on 148 out of 150 days.  What does this external app know that the "official" /reputation page does not?  Why are the two out of sync, and why can't the real page use the same data that the app is using?

Comment: Just guessing - the app isn't using the live databases, but an earlier copy?

Comment: The job to check for "Legendary" badges doesn't run so often. It likely will take a few days.

Comment: Just wait til you get that badge.  It's gonna be legen - wait for it...

Comment: ..........dary!

Comment: For whatever reason, I now have the badge!  Thanks all.